# Mysqli query inner join error

Tags: mysql

Whats wrong with this query

```
$yourfriendsbud = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT avatar,firstname,lastname,id
FROM people 
INNER JOIN friends
ON 
people.id=friends.zatrazio_id
WHERE status=0 AND dobio_id='$user_id' LIMIT 50");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($yourfriendsbud))
```

It reports the error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/u573639388/public_html/menu.php on line 64

line 64 is

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($yourfriendsbud))
```

Comment: You have to check for errors. `if (!$yourfriendsbud) echo mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: Show some more code please. Connection to db ... You should use prepared statement.

Comment: It says Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: That means you have an `id` column in both tables. You have to be more specific in the `SELECT`, using `SELECT people.id, avatar, firstname...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Answer (score 0):

That means you have an id column in both tables. You have to be more specific in the SELECT, using SELECT people.id, avatar, firstname...